# netsh - The syntax of the file, directory, or volume name is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

I am actually trying to make a script to change my network whenever I want to. But the netsh command result in an error. FYI, my OS is set to French Language.

Here is my code :

```
SET NomConnexion=ReseauLocal
SET IP=192.168.1.188
SET Masque=255.255.255.0
SET Passerelle=192.168.1.254

netsh interface IP set address "%NomConnexion%" static %IP% %Masque% %Passerelle% 1

SET DNS=8.8.8.8
SET DNS2=8.8.4.4
netsh interface IP set DNS "%NomConnexion%" static %DNS% primary
netsh interface ip add dns "%NomConnexion%" %DNS2% 2
```

Resulting with this error (x3) : "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".

I also tried without quotes, but it didn't work also.
I tried to save my .bat files with notepad++ & notepad.exe, with different encoding methods, but nothing changed.

Any idea ?

Comment: `netsh /?` for help.

Comment: The code you posted should not cause the error you describe, unless you messed around with the system's `%PATH%` variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution using @Gerhard Barnard comment.

I used this :

```
netsh interface show interface
```

To display all my interfaces names, and then take the good one and apply it to NomConnexion. Everything works now. Thanx !